# VueJS2 and the Window Object - how to use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2, jira-rest-api

I am trying to use a third-party API to collect some data from a user. I am unsure how to go about setting this up in the Vue instance.

Here's my test code in JSFIDDLE: [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/doss1/s3L75gc9/)
***To see the issue, choose the "DEF" dropdown and then select BRIEF and see the element at the bottom of the page 'Fill out the Brief form here'.***

> Snipped HTML code with custom trigger attribute:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning" v-if="(!selectedOffice.inJira) && (product ==='Brief')">Fill out the Brief <a href="#" class="myCustomTrigger"> form here</a></div>
```

> The JavaScript code for the data collector:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://organik.atlassian.net/s/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e-T/1gaygj/b/c/3d70dff4c40bd20e976d5936642e2171/_/download/batch/com.atlassian.jira.collector.plugin.jira-issue-collector-plugin:issuecollector-embededjs/com.atlassian.jira.collector.plugin.jira-issue-collector-plugin:issuecollector-embededjs.js?locale=en-US&collectorId=208a7651",
    type: "get",
    cache: true,
    dataType: "script"
});

/*  This is the script for specifying the custom trigger.  We've replaced 'myCustomTrigger' with 'feedback-button' */
 window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS =  {
    "triggerFunction": function(showCollectorDialog) {
        //Requires that jQuery is available! 
        jQuery(".myCustomTrigger").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            showCollectorDialog();
        });
    }};
```

Here's how I have my Vue instance set up:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    //testMessage: 'hello world',
    selectedOffice: '',
    selectedProducts: [],
    officeList: []
  }, //data
  created: function() {
    //get API JSON data here
    //data here for demo
    this.officeList = [{
      code: "ABC",
      inJira: true
    }, {
      code: "DEF",
      inJira: false
    }, {
      code: "GHI",
      inJira: true
    }, {
      code: "JKL",
      inJira: false
    }, {
      code: "External",
      inJira: false
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    clearProductsSelection() {
      return this.selectedProducts = [];
    }
  }
});
```

Any tips on how to utilize the window object within Vue so I can trigger the custom function? Nothing happens at the current moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding the following code to make this work:

```
 window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS =  {
    "triggerFunction": function(showCollectorDialog) {
       Vue.prototype.$showCollectorDialog = showCollectorDialog
    }};
```

And then the click handler was added to the view as so:

```
v-on:click="$showCollectorDialog"
```